# ExtJs5: How to read server response in Model.save

Tags: extjs5

I use `Model.save` to save data from the ExtJs form. Sometimes server returns operation status in following format:

```
{"success": false, "error": {"name": "Invalid Name"}}
```

The following code sends data from form to server:

```
var model = formPanel.getRecord();
model.save({
  callback: function(record, operation, success) {
    // operation.response is null,
    // and success === true
    // how to read server response here?
  }
})
```

Server response is treated as successful because HTTP status is 200. So I  I have to read server response to check operation status. But `operation.response` is `null` in `callback` function.

Here is my Model:

```
Ext.define('My.Model', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  idProperty: 'id',
  fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'auto'},
    {name: 'name', type: 'auto'}
  ],
  proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'api/v1/models',
    appendId: true,
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
    },
    writer: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
});
```

Question: how can I access server response after `Model.save`'s call?

More generic question: is it semantically correct to use `Model.load` or `Model.save` to populate/save the ExtJs form?

I'm using ExJs 5.0.1.1255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created some simple test code for this:

```
var Clazz = Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'api/v1/models'
    }
});

var instance = Ext.create('MyModel', {
    name: 'MyName'
});

instance.save({
    callback: function(record, operation) {

    }
});
```

The server responds with:

```
{
    success: true,
    something: 'else'
}
```

You can see this in a fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fhi

With this code, the callback has a `record` argument, and `record.data` contains the the original record  merged with the server response. In addition, you can do `operation.getResponse()` (rather than just `operation.response`) to get full access to the server's response.

In regard to your question on load vs save, if you use view models and bind the model that way, it kind of becomes moot as your form should always reflect the state of the model.

Comment: Oh, did they introduce server side view models in ExtJS ;p ?

Comment: operation.getResponse() really works, thanks! Unfortunately this method is marked as private in ExtJs docs.

Comment: If my method is moot, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: Well since you're not using view models your way is just fine IMO. It was just another thought about a way of doing things :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `model.save()` and `Model.load()` is definitely the correct thing to do.

In addition to providing a custom callback, you should investigate configuring a [custom proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest). In a custom proxy, you can provide your own implementation of the [`extractResponseData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-extractResponseData) method. This would let you centralise your need to examine the server response.